# C++ - Cannot convert from 'char []' to 'char[]'

Tags: c++, types, char

So I am very new to C++, and having a background in dynamic languages this is probably a newbie question. I was trying to write an age-old exercise, see below:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(char n[], int a) {           
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    int age;
    char name[];

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Person p("John", 25);
    return 0;
}
```

This throws the error:

```
main.cpp(8) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char []' to 'char []'
        There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions
to references or pointers to arrays
```

Why does it need to convert from the same type? This is my full code and full error, by the way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That is a bad (misleading, confusing) error message.  It is a legitimate error badly diagnosed, though.  You can't really make use of `char name[];` in a structure or class, either, but you haven't got to that error yet.  You need to define a size for the array, or use a `std::string`, or maybe (but probably not really advisable) play with `char *name;`.  However, if you choose `char *name`, you will have to deal with allocation during construction and release during destruction and worry about assignment and copy construction and move semantics and exception safety.

Comment: Using the Microsoft C++ compiler, which seems to have very confusing error messages. Guess they expect you to be using Visual Studio and not a command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a type called `char []`, but it's an *incomplete array type* which is a somewhat advanced topic. If it were compiling in strict mode, the compiler would have reported that an incomplete array cannot be a class member, and that should prevent the error you got. But actually you stumbled upon a GCC extension which is seldom compatible with C++ as it requires memory allocation by `malloc`.

Anyway, C++ does indeed have variable-length strings in the library, albeit not as a "native" type. You need to include `<string>`, and it is called `std::string`.

```
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string n, int a) {           
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    int age;
    std::string name;

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Person p("John", 25);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not assignable. You have to copy elements on each index to the other iteratively. For character arrays, you can use strcpy.

```
int a[5], b[5];

a = b; // Error
```

You should specify the size of the array. Use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of working on character arrays.

Comment: I was under the impression that C++ did not have a `string` type?

Comment: Where on earth did you get that impression? It's actually called ... `string`.

Comment: Sure, they are in C. But if you're using C++, use `string`.

Comment: if it didn't you could have rolled your own

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple: Try `std::string foo = "bar";` and make sure you have `#include <string>` before you do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code:

1. The type of `n` is `char*`: it is **not** an array but a pointer. You cannot pass built-in arrays as value parameters. You *could* pass it as a reference, though, e.g. using `char const (&n)[5]` (I'll get to the `const` below).
2. Even if you pass an array `name` is an array with no elements and actually illegal! You need to use a positive size for an array.
3. Lets assume you declared `name` as a member of type `char name[5];` and `n` as a reference to an array, you still wouldn't be able to assign these because arrays cannot be assigned. You could, however, copy them using, e.g.,

   ```
   std::copy(std::begin(n), std::end(n), std::begin(name));
   ```
4. The type of a string literal is `char const[N]` with `N` being the number of characters in the string literal. You cannot assign that to `char*`. In C++03 the assignment was required to be supported but deprecated and in C++11 the assignment isn't allowed anymore (although it is likely that compiler will allow it unless you enable a strict mode).
5. Not an error but a note: you should initialize your members, where possible, in the member initializer list, e.g. (assuming the member `name` has a suitable type):

   ```
   Person(char const* n, int a)
       : age(a)
   {
       strncpy(this->name, n, sizeof(this->name));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I compile the example code in g++ and what's going on becomes a little clearer:

```
so.cpp:5:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [0]’
```

This zero-length array is a "flexible array member". It must be the last data member of the class, and as with other arrays, you can't assign to it. If you can't use `std::string` for some reason, such as if your C++ module needs to present a certain API to C modules, try changing the last line of `Person` as follows:

```
    const char *name;
```

This will result in a working program with a const-correctness warning, which can be fixed by changing the first line of the constructor:

```
    Person(const char n[], int a) {
```

The final program, which compiles without warnings in g++:

```
#include <cstdio>
class Person
{
public:
    Person(const char n[], int a) {           
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    int age;
    const char *name;

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Person p("Jack", 14);
    std::puts(p.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that 'flexible array members' are a GCC (G++) extension to the C++11 standard.  (`g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic` should reveal that.)  They are part of C99 and C11, but that's a different language.

Comment: Note that although your `Person` constructor works OK with `"Jack"` as the initializer, if someone uses: `str::string j = "Jack"; Person jack (j, 14); j = "Jill";`, the chances are rather high that the pointer in `j.name` no longer contains a valid pointer to `"Jack"`. It might contain a valid pointer to `"Jill"`, or it might contain an invalid pointer (and which it contains is probably not defined).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error I get from g++

```
$ g++ -Wall example.cc -o example
example.cc: In constructor ‘Person::Person(char*, int)’:
example.cc:5:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [0]’
example.cc: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
example.cc:16:24: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

If I substitute `char n[]` and `char name[]` with `char *n` and `char *name`, you get

```
$ g++ -Wall example.cc -o example
example.cc: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
example.cc:16:24: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

I'm not sure why the compiler likes `char*`'s better in this case, but it does make more sense to use `char*`'s when representing strings in general.

Since you are writing in C++, the type `std::string` is generally preferred since it is more type-safe than `char*`. This will make code that compiles more robust.

Will all of that in mind, I would write the following code

```
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string n, int a) {           
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    int age;
    std::string name;

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Person p("Jack", 14);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re "it does make more sense to use char*'s when representing strings in general." No. In general it makes more sense to use `std::string` when representing strings in C++.